# How to limit text of span

Tags: html, css

I have a treeview created with html/js.  The element that displays the text is a span.

I want to limit the width of the span, as sometimes the text is very long.  For example, I want to show the first 20 characters only.  If longer than that, show an ellipses.

So I have tried setting a max-width, but this is not respected for a span.

If I change the span to a div, it works, but it completely changes the layout of the treeview.

Is there some way to achieve this? (I put 'LIMIT TEXT HERE' in the below to show the span to be limited.)

```
<ul class="tree-view-list">
        <li class="node-item">
            <i click.delegate="toggleItems(item)"
               if.bind="item.nodeAspect.isExpanded && item.children.length > 0"
               class="icon sf-icon-chevron-down p-r-half grow chevron"
               aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i click.delegate="toggleItems(item)"
               class="icon sf-icon-chevron-right p-r-half grow chevron"
               if.bind="!item.nodeAspect.isExpanded && item.children.length > 0"
               aria-hidden="true"></i>



            <div if.bind="item.nodeAspect.isEditing">
                <form>
                    <input blur.trigger="saveEdit(item)" attach-focus="true" type="text" value.bind="item.name">
                    <button style="display: none" click.delegate="saveEdit(item)"></button>
                </form>
            </div>

            <span class="e-treeview">

                <span if.bind="!item.nodeAspect.isEditing"
                      mouseover.delegate="onMouseOver(item)"
                      mouseout.delegate="onMouseOut(item)"
                      class="node-wrapper ${item.nodeAspect.isSelected ? 'node-is-selected e-active' : ''} ${item.nodeAspect.isHovering ? 'e-node-hover' : ''}"
                      click.delegate="nodeSelected(item)"
                      dblclick.delegate="nodeDoubleClick(item)">
                    <span draggable="true"
                          class="node-text"
                          contextmenu.delegate="showContextMenu($event, item)"
                          dragstart.delegate="dragStart($event, item)"
                          dragover.delegate="dragOver($event, item)"
                          drop.delegate="drop($event,item)">
                          <i class="tree-view-icon sf-icon-${item.itemType.icon}"></i> ${item.name}  LIMIT TEXT HERE
                    </span>

                </span>
            </span>
            <compose if.bind="item.nodeAspect.isExpanded" repeat.for="item of item.children" view="./tree-view.html"></compose>

        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general (simplified), you should put a `width` restriction (`min-width` works too).

For the width to be supported, the `display` should be `block` or `inline-block`.

You should tell the element to hide the `overflow` (`overflow: hidden`).

And tell it to put the `ellipsis` as `text-overflow`.

And in order to prevent the text from wrapping, you should `white-space: nowrap` to make it hold on a single line.

Is the inline-block an option for your treeview ?

Like this:

```
.node-text {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need to use JavaScript for that.

Here is my solution using jQuery to check the length and replace if over 20

```js
if ($("#myspan").html().length > 20) {
  short_text = $("#myspan").html().substr(0, 20);
  $("#myspan").html(short_text + "...");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>This is some text that really should be shorter. I hope it gets reduced</span>
<br>
<span id="myspan">This is some text that really should be shorter. I hope it gets reduced</span>
```

Comment: I was looking for a css answer, not js answer.

Answer (score 1):

change the span to [display:inline-block] and give it a [max-width] with [text-overflow:ellipsis] and [overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;vertical-align: middle;]

```css
p {
  font: 16px/28px tahoma;
  color: #333;
}
p span {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ex vel <span>doming splendide aliquando. Mei petentium scripserit cu.</span> Vim ferri tantas ne. Ad laudem doming inimicus pri, cum minimum adversarium te. Enim dicit id sit, magna dicit omnium et vix.
</p>
```